# What is the 'if key == arr[low]: return low' doing in Interpolation search?

Tags: python, search, interpolation

I've seen a few implementations of Interpolation search in Python that uses

```
if key == arr[low]:
    return low
```

After the while-loop, like this:

```
def interpolation_search(arr, key):

    low = 0
    high = len(arr) - 1

    while arr[high] != arr[low] and arr[low] <= key <= arr[high]:
        mid = low + ((key - arr[low]) * (high - low) // (arr[high] - arr[low]))

        if key == arr[mid]:
            return mid
        elif key < arr[mid]:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1

    if key == arr[low]:
        return low

    return -1
```

What is that doing? I've run a bunch of tests with various kinds of lists (even distribution, uneven, etc) and searching for every item in the list but I haven't been able to see a difference regardless of if that if-statement is there or not.

An example of the algorithm with the if-statement: https://www.techiedelight.com/interpolation-search/

And without the if-statement: https://www.baeldung.com/java-interpolation-search

I've run the code on arr = range(200) as well as a sorted array with length 200 containing random integers from 0 - 1000, with a few duplicates. The if-statement doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: I guess there'll be exceptional inputs where the while loop exits, without a proper value found. Then there is one last check to see if the searched-for value is on the current `low` index of the array. If not, it's simply not found.

Comment: Try with `[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]` and `key = 9`.

Comment: It looks like the above algorithm is flawed: with `[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]` and `key = 0`, it returns `'0 not found'`. Unless that is somehow intended. (It should also raise an exception, instead of returning a string. If only because it normally returns an integer; returning a string will cause strange exceptions further down the line. So the string return is also flawed in my opinion.)

Comment: @9769953 thank you so much! I was looking for the edge case but I had no idea what to search for. Yep, this makes sense now. Cheers

Comment: Yeah the actual algorithm is a bit broken, I'm still trying to work it out but was stuck on the if-statement. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, looking at this again the algorithm only works on ascending ordered lists, not on descending. The example you gave with `key = 9` is caught because the if-statement catches it but only accidentally. The algorithm isn't meant to work with incorrectly sorted lists. So it feels like that if-statement isn't there to catch the one case that shouldn't be caught anyway.

Comment: Hm, ok. It also seems a bit odd to call it "interpolation" if it always matches to an *exact* value in the input list; perhaps that's a contextual meaning of interpolation that I'm not aware of. But it does feel like a search algorithm (I assume using this meaning of interpolation), which makes it a bit odd that the data should already be sorted. That probably means this should be a more optimised version for a generic search algorithm, for when the input data is guaranteed to be in order?

Comment: Is `[9, 9, 9, 9]` considered sorted? (With `key = 9` obviously.)

Comment: Yep, this is a search algorithm used on ordered data (preferably evenly distributed): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search
There just seems to be so many versions of this out there, some with a slight reworking of the while-statement, others with no catching if-statement at the end. I'm so confused haha.

Comment: Actually, maybe that if-statement is meant to catch that particular case? If the list only contains one value then the while loop will never trigger, but you still want to be able to check if the item is in that list so you can do a quick check before returning -1. Maybe that's it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if-statement below the while loop may be there to catch the case where the input array consists of only the same values, like `[9, 9, 9, 9]`; or even of one value, `[9]`. In that case, the while loop is never entered, and the if statement becomes necessary:

```
interpolation_search([9, 9, 9, 9], 9)
```

and

```
interpolation_search([9], 9)
```

will both enter the if-statement body.

---

Side notes:

- When the value is not present, an exception should be raised, instead of a string returned.
  The return value of a string when the value is not found is a bad choice, in my opinion, since there is still a single value returned, and it appeared the function ran successfully. But when later on, that value is used as an index into an array, there'll be an exception that has its roots in this function, but the exception won't show that.
- in Python, you would just do `arr.index(key)`, which replaces this whole function (and may be more optimised). Arguably, what you have here, is a C-style function, which happens to be coded in Python, but really shouldn't be used in Python. Also, this ignores NumPy, which would be more suitable for large arrays (the variable name `arr` is more indicative of NumPy arrays though, instead of something like `lst` or `my_list`, the latter which tends to point to Python lists).

Comment: Yep, this is definitely the answer. I have updated the question body with the correct return value. As for `arr.index(key)` that method uses linear search, as described here:https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ee171a26c1169abfae534b08acc0d95c6e45a22a/Modules/arraymodule.c#L1120.
Interpolation search function improves on that for evenly distributed and sorted lists. Thanks for the help!